# facebook login button and authentications

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am not sure what it means by "unknown" when I use FB.getLoginStatus. shall I redirect to the auth dialog box? 
I have the login button plugin on my page

but it works when I log using my own facebook account.
when I open the page without logging in, the button wouldn't even show up. 
Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/flow/

> ```
> response.status   Description
> connected         user is logged into Facebook, has authorized your app
> notConnected      user is logged into Facebook, has not authorized your app
> unknown           user is logged out of Facebook.
> ```

Comment: Thank you! that makes more sense